# What is the algorithm for random numbers in X++? [AX]

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

What is the algorithm to have random reals using x++ in Dynamics AX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old way (and only if using Axapta 3.0) is to use the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa642783(v=AX.50).aspx) class which is listed in the AOT under System Documentation\Classes. It will return a 15 bit integer only. See [AX Daily](http://axdaily.blogspot.com/2010/01/generating-random-number.html).

But like Alex, I will prefer using the newer [xGlobal::randomPositiveInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc574456%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).

```
dice = (xGlobal::randomPositiveInt32() mod 6) + 1;
```

Comment: is there a method to generate random negative numbers?

Comment: Sure: -xGlobal::randomPositiveInt32()
Did you see the minus?

Comment: Or: (xGlobal::randomPositiveInt32() mod 7) - 3, to generate -3 to +3.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily generate a positive int with this method, then just turn it into a real and divide after if you want decimals.

i = xGlobal::randomPositiveInt32();